why do I get undefined when after I logged in using auth js? AuthJS(V5)
I've been following the docs but I still end up getting undefined on my first render, why do i get. The RootProvider is just a react-query. I'm trying to create a dynamic sidebar wherein if the the role === admin, it will render different sidebar component.
what I did is I created a hook that I will just call to whenever I need the user.
app/hooks/user-current.ts
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";

export const useCurrentUser = () => {
    const session = useSession()

    return session.data?.user
}

RootLayout.tsx

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: Readonly<{
  children: React.ReactNode;
}>) {
  const session = await auth();

  return (
    <SessionProvider session={session}>
      <html lang="en">
        <body
          className={`${geistSans.variable} ${geistMono.variable} antialiased`}
        >
          <RootProvider>
            <Toaster />
            {children}
          </RootProvider>
        </body>
      </html>
    </SessionProvider>
  );
}


This is my sidebar coming from shadcn tutorial

export function AppSidebar() {

  const session = useCurrentUser()
  console.log(session?.role)

  return (
    <Sidebar>
      <SidebarContent>
        <SidebarGroup>
          <SidebarGroupLabel>Application</SidebarGroupLabel>
          <SidebarGroupContent>
            <SidebarMenu>
              {items.map((item) => (
                <SidebarMenuItem key={item.title}>
                  <SidebarMenuButton asChild>
                    <Link href={item.url}>
                      <item.icon />
                      <span>{item.title}</span>
                    </Link>

                  </SidebarMenuButton>
                </SidebarMenuItem>
              ))}
            </SidebarMenu>
          </SidebarGroupContent>
        </SidebarGroup>

      </SidebarContent>
      <SidebarFooter>
        <SignOutButton />
      </SidebarFooter>
    </Sidebar>
  )
}

Now the main problem is after I successfully log in, and when I consoe.log() is get undefined, and i need to refresh my browser before it shows the role.

I'm not sure which version of authjs you're using but I'm not sure if you need to be putting the session inside the provider like that.
I'm using auth-js and can't replicate this - the session will start as undefined but re-render and be populated. Can you try removing session={session} from the ?

Hi @serp002, I'm currently using the beta version https://authjs.dev/

Did you try removing the session from the provider? I dont see anywhere in the documentation where it says to do this.

I did, but I still get the same, I still get undefined

Strange, not sure whats going on there. Only other thing i can see different from my setup is that i have the  inside the body, not outside of the html like you have. Not sure if that will change anything but could try that.
